# Beyond Compare merges - is there a "take left for all"?

Tags: merge, beyondcompare

When we do merges with Beyond Compare there is a "Take Left" or "Take Right" option for each conflict..  is there any way to do a "Take Left for all conflicts"?  I've seen this in other merge tools (Kidff3 has it) but I can't see it in Beyond Compare.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think through my answer completely so I deleted it.  I don't believe there's a way to do it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Change the display filter to **Show Conflicts** (View->Show Conflicts), then in one of the input panes use **Select All** (Ctrl+A) followed by **Take Left** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) or **Take Right** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).

Answer (score 3):

To follow up on what Craig said, **Beyond Compare version 3** operates slightly differently. **View->Show Conflicts** is now **View->Show Context**.

Also,

- `Take Left` is now `Copy to Left` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)
- `Take Right` is now `Copy to Right` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

The two mentioned points could be vexing for someone who reads this with V3, because `Take` and `Copy` could be seen as opposites.

Comment: My comments were for v3.  Beyond Compare 3 Pro has a dedicated merge interface that takes 3 input files (yours, mine, and a shared ancestor) and shows the automatically merged results in a fourth output panel.  The commands you're referring to only appear in the 2-way compare, which you can use for merging, but it can't detect conflicts, handle the merge automatically, or tell you which side a change came from.  That is how we document "merges" for v2 and v3 Standard, which don't support the full merge interface though.